# Check if string contains other string elements

Tags: c++, objective-c

I am trying to check if string contains elements from different string in specific order.

For example:

large string: thisisstring

small string: hssg

it should return true.

I only figured out how to check if string contains whole other string but not parts.
This is the code that I wrote for checking for now:

```
if ([largestring rangeOfString:smallstring].location != NSNotFound) {
   printf("contains");
}
```

Comment: but what if there are letters between the letters of small string.

like thisisstring and hssg example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this, at least, no built in way that I know of.  You would have to iterate through each letter of your small string and find the first letter that matches your large string.

Each time you find a matching letter, you loop to the next smallstring letter, but instead only begin searching at the index after you found the previous letter.

EDIT:
some pseudo code, untested, may have syntax errors:

```
int foundChar = 0;
for (int l = 0; l < strlen(smallstring); l++)
{
  bool found = false;
  for (; foundChar < strlen(largestring); foundChar++)
  {
    if (smallstring[l] == largestring[foundChar])
    {
      // We break here because we found a matching letter.
      // Notice that foundChar is still in scope so we preserve
      // its value for the next check.
      found = true;
      foundChar++;  // Increment so the next search starts with the next letter.
      break;
    }
  }
  // If we get down here, that means we've searched all of the letters
  // and found no match, we can result with a failure to find the match.
  if (found == false)
  {
    return false;
  }
}

// If we get here, it means every loop resulted in a valid match.
return true;
```

Answer (score 5):

1. If there are no more characters to search for from the small string, return true.
2. Starting from the position after the most recently found character in the large string, do a linear search for the first character from the small string that has not yet been searched for.
3. If the character was not found, return false.
4. Start back at 1.